# External JavaScript launched within another JavaScript

Tags: javascript, case

I'm currently trying to create a 'database' for some locations in my town for other students. 
Okey, here is the idea:

1. I got a map, with all the locations pinned
2. These pins launch a javascript onclick wich writes a little article to the side of the map.
3. I want a script within this script wich (inception-style), dependant on day (Case-script) writes the locations opening and closing time.

I'm quite fresh at this, and not sure if there is any logical reason for this not to work, here is my code:

the first javascript:

```
brukbar = "<h4>Brukbar & Supa</h4>
<img src=__PICTURE class=bilde_lite><br>
<span class=beskrivelse_klikk>
<b>&Aring;pent: </b> **->> THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE SCRIPT FOR OPENING DAY <<-** <br>
<b>Rating: </b> 
<br><hr>
__DESCRIPTION LOCATION__
</span>
<hr> <a href=# target=_blank>External page</a><br>"
```

And here is the case:

```
    var d=new Date();
    var theDay=d.getDay();
    switch (theDay)
    {
    case 1:
    document.write("08-20");
    break;
    case 2:
    ....
    case 0:
    document.write("08-20");
    }
```

Is there a way to write this as a function (above), then launch it within the other script?
I tried, but all I was able to do, was to write the opening time to a blank site.

I might be doing this in an incredibly stupid way, if anyone got any suggestions id glady give those a shot (Ps. i don't want to make a page for each loaction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var brukbar = "<h4>Brukbar & Supa</h4><img src=__PICTURE class=bilde_lite><br>    <span class=beskrivelse_klikk><b>&Aring;pent: </b>"
+ func() +
"<br><b>Rating: </b><br><hr>__DESCRIPTION LOCATION__</span><hr> <a href=# target=_blank>External page</a><br>";

function func()
{
  var d=new Date();
  var theDay=d.getDay();
  switch (theDay)
    {
    case 1:
     return "08-20";
    break;
    case 2:
    ....
    case 0:
      return "08-20";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I undestood is: you have a piece o HTML and you want to write a custom message inside of this HTML.

Where you want to put your content, create something like this:

```
<div id="custom-div-content"></div>
```

And then on your switch case:

```
document.getElementById("custom-div-content").innerHtml("your custm message");
```

What the code above does is really simple: gets the div element with the specified id ("custom-div-content") and changes its inner HTML content.

Hope I helped.